# Is it advisable to avoid titles that are colorful or consisting of wordplays?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Of course when authors write papers they make the title *intentionally* colorful to generate interest (e.g. *Let's get deranged!* by John C.Baez). Should this practice be avoided in main even if the user adds background, motivation or appropriate research in the full question?

Comment: As with titles of articles, I would say; we want the titles to be informative. But it is generally difficult to come up with a *good* colorful/pun title. Most attempts fall flat, and I suspect the same would end up being true in the main site...

Comment: I actually think that boring, uninformative titles are a more common problem on this site. You know, threads like "A combinatorics problem", "Calculus Help" and ilk.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree that there is also a risk of the questions being ill-formed especially if one runs amok with puns.

Comment: @J.M. It would be then be a matter of...ready for this?... _moderation_. In all seriousness, while questions such as: _Can one both have and eat his pi?_ dealing with, say, 'non-constructive proof of irrationality of pi' may add the needed gloss/advertisement esp. to outsiders of the field, it would also open up many meaningless, soft, phil. questions?

Comment: It's a bit hard to speculate, I'd say. Like I said, most titles here are pedestrian (which is fine) or uninformative (not so fine).

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't worry about it in general; at worst, the title could be changed.  As opposed to an article published in a journal, if it does fall flat it is easy to change the title.

Answer (score 5):

They should be used when they help the reader understand something; they should be avoided when they distract from the topic.  Thus ''Hearing the Shape of a Drum'' (a famous paper) helps the reader understand what the topic is about.